# Order of KeyEvents processing in Winforms with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have subclassed form with 3 controls-NumericUpDown in it.
Here is main form' code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Inherits cls_subform

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.KeyPreview = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub NumericUpDown1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.KeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            Debug.Print "Control's ENTER is pressed"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is simplified frm_subform code:

```
Public Class cls_subform
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub onKeyDown(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
           e.Handled = True
           e.SuppressKeyPress = True
           Debug.Print "Subclassed ENTER is pressed"
        End If

        MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This obviously work propper.
But problem is that I would like to handle control's event handler NumericUpDown1_KeyDown FIRST. And then if it is not "handled" I would like to handle onKeyDown event handler on frm_subform.
If I set KeyPreview to False then I can catch control's event but then onKeyDown is not fired.

Is there a way to get desired functionality?
That FIRST will be fired control's _KeyDown handler and then form's onKeyDown handler?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This seems like an [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): if we know the problem you are trying to solve there is probably a far better solution based on a different starting point.

Comment: In short. Under subclass I have code to manage SelectNextControl to navigate control's with arrow keys. That work's fine. But there are cases where I have to suppress navigation what depends on control's situation. Of course, real code is too complex to post here.

Comment: Please expand (that brief information is insufficient) *and* put as introduction to the question.

Comment: No. That would lead us to X Y Problem. Instead of that I would like to get solution in described way. Without ProcessCmdKey, low level keyboard catching or API programming. "That can't be done that way" will also be a good answer.

Comment: You are, it appears, not understanding what an XY Problem is: you have a problem, you think intercepting keyboard events will fix it, but are stuck on that solution. However – given event ordering – it is unlikely that is the best way. But it is hard to say without an description of the reason why you want to manipulate keyboard events in that way.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to understand. Most of the normal GUI toolkits have logical event distribution from control to form/application and that chain can be intercepted anywhere in program regarding of programmer's  needs what is as seem's here not a case since I am not able to get simple answer or workable code based on GIVEN example regardless of the way on how this will be eventually used.

Comment: You can't change the order of the events. On the form keydown event you could suppress or not depending which control has focus.

Comment: So the_lotus, what is the point of that if you press a key on input in say NumericUpDown that Form "know" about this before than that specific NumericUpDown? What I'm trying to say all the time: On my opinion this is not "normal".